# Wordpress admin page's login form auto-submits

Tags: php, wordpress

When I go to `localhost:PORT/ADMIN.php`, I am brought to the login page to sign in as an administrator. As soon as this page loads, it displays:

> ERROR: The username field is empty.
> ERROR: The password field is empty.

… before I've even clicked the "Log In" button. It also shakes the form. It behaves the same way when I refresh the page.

Is there a way to prevent the form from automatically submitting on first load?

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is experiencing a similar problem, I was able to fix the issue by modifying functions.php. I created a function (that fires on login_init) that checks if there is any post data for the password field. If there isn't, then I created a blank Wordpress error, which has the effect of clearing any other errors.